# Extracting group from regex

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I am new to using regex and having some issues understanding how to extract a group from a regular expression. I have a text file (example.txt):

```
libstuff-example1 (>= 6.3.2),
libpackage-example2 (>= 5.2.1),
libtest-example3 (>= 5.2.1)
```

I am trying to extract the "5.2.1" only from the libpackage line and put it into a variable for a bash script. I have tried doing

```
cat example.txt | grep -oP "libpackage-[a-z- (>=]+(.*)[)],"
```

But it gives me the entire line instead of that "5.2.1" section. How do I extract the first group from that line so I only get "5.2.1"?

Comment: `grep` doesn't have any way of accessing groups. `-o` prints the entire match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sh
val=$(grep -Po 'libpackage-.* \K[0-9.]+' example.txt)
```

*Details*:

- `-Po` - enables the PCRE regex engine (`P`) and outputting matches only (with `o`)
- `libpackage-.* \K[0-9.]+` - matches `libpackage-`, then any text, a space, then omits all this text matched, and then matches and returns one or more digits or dots.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/r5Rg7I):

```sh
s='libstuff-example1 (>= 6.3.2),
libpackage-example2 (>= 5.2.1),
libtest-example3 (>= 5.2.1)'

val=$(grep -Po 'libpackage-.* \K[0-9.]+'  <<< "$s")
echo "$val"
# => 5.2.1
```

A GNU `awk` way:

```sh
val=$(awk -F'[ ()]+' '/^libpackage-/{print $3}' example.txt)
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/FTH8Qj).

Here, `-F'[ ()]+'` sets a field separator as one or more spaces or parentheses,  `/^libpackage-/` finds the line(s) starting with `libpackage-` and `{print $3}` prints ("returns") the value of Field (Column) 3.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```sh
var=$(sed -nE '/libpackage/s/.* ([0-9.]+).*/\1/p' file)

echo "$var"
5.2.1
```